# One validation for many model or how to right to do validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have 7 model  Attach that set period of attache date for other model. I need to validate that date of attache do not have intersection periud for example:

```
class AttachNetworkToUser < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :dt_begin, :dt_end, :network_id, :user_id
  validates :dt_begin, :dt_end, :network_id, :user_id, :presence => true

  belongs_to :network
  belongs_to :user

  validate :period_attach?


  def period_attach?
    user = AttachNetworkToUser.select("id, dt_begin, dt_end").where("network_id = :network_id  " , { :network_id => self.network_id} )
    user.each do |t|
      if ( (self.dt_begin >= t.dt_begin and self.dt_begin <= t.dt_end) or (self.dt_end >= t.dt_begin and self.dt_end <= t.dt_end) ) or (self.dt_begin < t.dt_begin and self.dt_end > t.dt_end )
        self.errors[:dt_begin] << " intersection periud! You can consolidate with " + (t.dt_end+1).to_s
      end
      if self.dt_begin > self.dt_end
        self.errors[:dt_begin] << " can not be more dt_end"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

It looks like code smell. And in other Attache model i have repeated code of this validation but with other parameters something like this:`{:Attach=>self,:user_id=>self.user_id,:network_id=>self.network_id,:dt_begin=>self.dt_begin,:user_id=>self.user_id}`

How correctly resolve this aim. 
Maybe put validation code in other class and send parameter like this:`AttachModelValidator.new({:Attach=>self,:user_id=>self.user_id,:network_id=>self.network_id,:dt_begin=>self.dt_begin,:user_id=>self.user_id}).valid`

Answer (score 0):

Normally I would say keep all validations in each of the models, in order for the code to be well understood.

Technically it is possible to do that:

If your fields had the same names in the various models, you could write all the validations once in a module, and put your models under that same module.

In case your fields names are different, you can define a method in a shared module, to receive the fields names and perform the validation.

Again, I would not recommend doing this. Unless you have a common logic you want to share between the models.

Cheers.